# Custom texture while rendering plane in ARCore - Android

Tags: android, arcore

After detecting the plane, ArFragment renders white dots on surface where you can tap and put 3d objects. 
From PlaneRenderer class we can hide the default texture.

```
ArFragment arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
arFragment.getArSceneView().getPlaneRenderer().setVisible(false);
```

But instead of hiding i want to add my custom texture. I am unable to find any documentation for setting this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the texture on the material used by the plane renderer.

For example, if you have a png in assets to use for the texture named "trigrid.png":

`setPlaneTexture("trigrid.png");`

```
  /**
   * Sets the plane renderer texture.
   * @param texturePath - Path to texture to use in the assets directory.
   */
  private void setPlaneTexture(String texturePath) {

    Texture.Sampler sampler = Texture.Sampler.builder()
            .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
            .setMagFilter(Texture.Sampler.MagFilter.LINEAR)
            .setWrapModeR(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
            .setWrapModeS(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
            .setWrapModeT(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
            .build();

    Texture.builder().setSource(() -> getAssets().open(texturePath))
            .setSampler(sampler)
            .build().thenAccept((texture) -> {
      arSceneView.getPlaneRenderer().getMaterial()
              .thenAccept((material) -> {
                material.setTexture(MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture);
                material.setFloat(MATERIAL_UV_SCALE,10f);
              });
    }).exceptionally(ex ->{ Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read an asset file", ex);
    return null;} );
  }
```